# How to set a default date and time on a owl-date-time componenent

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I am sure I am missing something very obvious but for the life of me I can't figure out how to set a default date and time on this component.

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm"
         [(ngModel)]="value"
         [owlDateTime]="dt1"
         [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1"
         placeholder="Date Time"
         (dateTimeChange)="onChange($event)">
<owl-date-time #dt1 [firstDayOfWeek]="1"></owl-date-time>
```

and the Typescript part

```
export class DatetimeSelectorComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
public options: any[];
public value: moment.Moment;
_onChange: (value: any) => void;

constructor() {}
writeValue(value: any) {
  this.value = value;
}

registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => void) {
  this._onChange = fn;
}

registerOnTouched() {}
onChange(value: any) {
  this._onChange(this.value);
}
```

Originally it is from here, https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime

I literally just want to hardcode a date that will display when the page loads, after I figure that out then I am pretty sure I can enhance from there.

Comment: Have you tried to modify `value` in the Component -- I see you set the type, but perhaps try to set the default as well `public value: moment.Moment = moment()`?

Comment: Yeah tried that, I have been able to get a value assigned but it won't display on the front end

Comment: `public dateTime = new moment();` worked ok in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-48cshb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmoment-js%2Fmoment-js.component.ts). I'm wondering if there is something off with the `ControlValueAccessor` implementation

Comment: thanks your help got me to figure it out on my side, needed to set the value in as FormControl and then it worked on the component. added info as an answer

Answer (score 5):

In the end adding this worked, I'm sure I am missing some basic understanding here but for now, this has sorted me out 100%

```
  this.filterGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  startDate: new FormControl(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)))
});
```

startDate being the component

```
<so-datetime-selector formControlName="startDate"  ></so-datetime-selector>
```